# Merge a Subversion Branch back in to the Trunk and retain Revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

My subversion project has a branch that's been used to develop a major new release of the product.  Now that the product has been launched, it's time to merge that branch back in to the Truck.

I'm using VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN to work with the SVN Server.

Based on the TortoiseSVN documentation, the process seems to be:

> a.  Check Out the Trunk to a Working
>   Copy.
>
> b.  Run the Merge command to apply the
>   Branch changes to the Working Copy.  I've tried the Merge Dialog in TortoiseSVN and this attempt from the command line:
>
> `svn merge --reintegrate https://domain.com/project/branches/example`
>
> c.  Commit the Working Copy back to
>   the Trunk.

While this process will result in the Trunk having all of the latest code, it also means that I lose all of the revisions in the Branch.  That's not acceptable.  I want to be able to see the progress during development, and keep all of the check-in comments.

There must be a better way to accomplish this merge, right?

Comment: It's possible that this may be the issue (case changes in the domain name of the SVN URL).  If that were the case, is there any way I can "undo" this and get the merge to work?   http://old.nabble.com/Why-Merge-Tracking-is-disabled--td22419634.html

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of SVN and Tortoise SVN (1.5+) have a merge tracking feature; this allows Tortoise SVN to display revisions from branches. In the Tortoise SVN Log Message window, if you check "Include merged revisions" you will be able to see all of the commits that were made to the branch.

Comment: I see that checkbox in the Show Log dialog, but it doesn't work.  It still only shows the revisions from the Trunk, and the revisions where the merged Trunk + Branch code was committed.  This is what makes me think the approach I outlined above is not retaining the revision details from the Branch.

Comment: +1. @Axeva - you probably want to expand on your second step on how you do the merge.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the actual SVN command I've tried.